# Could not remove dir [...] /code_cache/.ll/ : No such file or directory (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

Nothing changed in the code, it just stopped projecting the app in the emulator, Logcat says what's in the title. The app is a very simple game skeleton for now, no errors, just some warning.

"W/System: A resource failed to call close." is the last message in the "Run" window.

The problem seems to be the inability to delete cache files due to their inexistence.

Please hepl.

I'm trying to build a very simple game, I was trying to sort out how to insert a joystick in one of the layouts and was adding a database. Again the emulator stopped working randomly, due to no code modification.

Comment: Try "wipe data" on the emulator and try again?

Comment: Did you import the project recently, like from github? I had similar issue after not properly import code, after file->new->import project app started working.

Comment: @KenWolf Wipe data worked, thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the emulator can get into an improper state and rather than trying to diagnose and fix what is happening it is easier to start over from a clean state.

Try "Wipe Data" from the emulator menu and try again.

[image]

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#emulator

Comment: This doesn't just happen in emulators; is there a way to clean up the mess for just that one app, without doing a factory reset of the whole phone just because android studio messed up something with that app?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error show after 3 times debug app in row in android studio. You can do a step of bottom steps:

- unplug your phone and plug another phone or emulator and run app successfully
- uninstall your app and unpluge your phone from computer and then restart your phone then run successfully