# Can't use mqtt in physical device

Tags: android, mqtt

I'm trying to develop an app to subscribe to a mqtt topic and receive messages. Some hours ago everything worked properly in the emulator and my physical smartphone, however I guess that I touch some libraries or something and I can't use mqtt in my physical device. I'm connecting to a public broker.
"tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883"

The program said some error about not cleaning the cache but I'm not sure if it's about that.
As I said before the app has correctly connect to the mqtt broker some hours ago.

`dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.1.0'
implementation 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.1.1'`


  <service
        android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" >
    </service>
```

`Could not remove dir '/data/data/com.example.app6/code_cache/.ll/': No such file or directory 2023-06-30 14:57:18.997   499-499   audit                   auditd                               E  type=1400 audit(1688129838.990:26677): avc:  granted  { execute } for  pid=7749 comm="re-initialized>" path="/data/data/com.example.app6/code_cache/startup_agents/8dee6a62-agent.so" dev="mmcblk0p69" ino=7188 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c0,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c0,c257,c512,c768 tclass=file SEPF_SM-T290_11_0004 audit_filtered`

Comment: Have you seen/tried: [Could not remove dir \[...\] /code_cache/.ll/ : No such file or directory (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75890199/295004)